# Display image on jsp page through Servlet

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am making a small application which uploads a image for authenticated user into database and displays all the images that were previously uploaded dynamically through servlet.

I retrieve images at page load from database using this code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<jsp:include page="/RetrieveImagesServlet.do"></jsp:include>
</head>
```

This sets the user images in the page request and is working fine.

Now to display image data in table format i use jstl. Since user image objects contains image in `byte[]` format so I invoke a servlet to print the image file as below.

```
<c:forEach var="imageDto" items="${requestScope.userImages}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${imageDto.getSerialNumber()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${imageDto.getImageName() }"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${imageDto.getImageSize()}"></c:out></td>
                    <td>
                        <c:set var="imageDto" scope="request" value="${imageDto}"></c:set>
                        <jsp:include page="/ImageDisplayServlet.do"></jsp:include> 
                        <c:remove var="imageDto" scope="request" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

The line `<jsp:include page="/ImageDisplayServlet.do"></jsp:include>` included in above code invokes a servlet to display which contains the code below

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    final ImageDto imageDto = (ImageDto) request.getAttribute("imageDto");
    System.out.println(imageDto.getImageName());
    final OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(imageDto.getImageFile());
    outputStream.close();
```

I am able to get the image in invoked servlet as it is able to print the imageName but it throws illegalStateException at `final OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();`.

Please guide me where I am wrong and how can I display image on jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how browsers and HTTP work. When you load an HTML page, you make a HTTP request. The response to the request is a page containing HTML code. For example:

```
<img src="someImage.png" />
```

The browser then parses the HTML, sees that there is an `img` tag, and then sends a second, different request to `someImage.png`. And the response to this second request is the bytes of the image.

You're trying to send, in the response to the first request, the HTML code *and* the bytes of the image. That can't work. The HTML page generated by the JSP must include an `img` tag, pointing at the servlet which will send the bytes of the image to the response. For example:

```
<img src="ImageDisplayServlet.do?imageId=${imageDto.id}" />
```

Comment: Yes now I understand that and finally I am doing it just like you told. But I wanted that if I have gone to my database for images first time it should return all images data and I don't have to go back for each imageId to get the image from the database. Is there any way or I have to hit the database for each imageId to get the image when I have already once went to get all images.

Comment: Your first query shouldn't load all the image bytes, since having the bytes at this moment is useless (unless you keep them in a cache, waiting for the next requests to come, but that will make your code stateful, and you won't know when to clear the cache).